# Recoil velocity of atom after photon absorption

Tags: photons, momentum, energy-conservation, velocity, absorption

I'm trying to calculate the recoil velocity of a stationary atom after absorbing a photon, in terms of $E$ and $m$.

I've tried manipulating relativistic equations, keeping in mind conservation of energy and momentum, but no answer is making sense.

$E = pc$ (for a massless photon) and $E = mc^2$ (for a stationary atom)

The total relativistic energy is given as $E = KE + mc^2$

So $E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + mc^2$

$v=\frac{p}{m}$, so the above becomes $E = \frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{p}{m}\right)^2 + mc^2$

I'm assuming the Lorentz factor isn't needed as the photon travels at light-speed, $c$?

Once I did this I plugged in the given values for $E$ and $m$ to  find the magnitude of the velocity, but the answer I got was in the order of $10^{-17}$... this seems really small... as if I've unnecessarily divided by $c^2$ somewhere?

Comment: The change of energy of the atom is equal to the energy of the photon. The $mc^2$ term should cancel if you take the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with your final equation:
$$E=\frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{p}{m}\right)^2+mc^2$$ 
$$E=\frac{p^2}{2m}+mc^2$$ 
$$p=\sqrt{2m(E-mc^2)}$$ 
Now, use the law of conservation of momentum as follows
$$p=mv$$
Where $p=h\cdot \nu /c$ is momentum of photon &

$mv$ is the momentum of atom after collision
Thus, we can find out the velocity of recoil either by substituting energy $E$ or frequency of photon $\nu$

Comment: I managed to get p=sqrt(2m(E−mc^2)) but with the given values I have for E (10.2eV) and m (940 MeV) my calculator comes up with syntax errors, so I thought this was wrong...